# Will I still be able to use the Chromebook & my docs/data, If I get a Chromebox?

Tags: google-chrome, google-docs

Will I still be able to use the Chromebook If I get a Chromebox?

I'm on my 2nd CB, and was unable to use my original CB (wouldn't accept my log in, saying user already existed.) I had to redo/reenter what I could, but lost all my original docs!

¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Documents are not stored on the chromebook - they are stored within the account you create with google - have you tried logging into your chrome account via a web browser? Try logging in with your old username and password then look in the 'Drive' section to see your documents.

Answer (score 0):

As all documents created on a chromebook are stored within the account, your documents will also be available on any other device you choose to use.